# HTTP client returning result as null

Tags: go, httpclient

We are running core go server in production under load balancer and other stuff.

Now when goroutine count(with pprof trace) is more than 2500, our HTTP client is returning nil as result.

[image: PPROD Trace]

Here is my code for HTTP client.

```
client := &http.Client{
Timeout:   time.Second * 130,
Transport: netTransport,
CheckRedirect: func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
    return http.ErrUseLastResponse
},
}
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 30*time.Second)
defer cancel()
go func() {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        log.Error(ctx.Err()) // prints "context deadline exceeded"
        return
    }
}()
vars := mux.Vars(r)
validateTokenURL = authURL + "/" + vars["resource"] + "/authorized" + "?url=" + path
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", validateTokenURL, nil)
req.Header = r.Header
req = req.WithContext(ctx)
res, error := client.Do(req)

if error != nil {
    log.Error("The group's number increased tremendously!")
    return nil, nil, false
}
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
if err != nil {
    log.Error(err.Error())
}
json.Unmarshal(body, &responseBody)
res.Body.Close()
if _, ok := responseBody["data"]; ok && strings.Compare(reflect.TypeOf(responseBody["data"]).String(), "string") == 0 && strings.Compare(responseBody["data"].(string), "ok") == 0 {
    return responseBody, res, true
}
return responseBody, res, false
}
```

I have set ulimit to approx 8 GB, plus we have 16 GB as RAM. Memory uses is less than 20%.

Can anyone help us to figure it out what we are missing?

Comment: What is the req.StatusCode in the nil cases?

I also think the server code is more important for this issue.

Comment: Haven't traced yet, +1 for suggesting.

Comment: If it's the server that has the high goroutine count (it's unclear from the question but that's the impression I get), then we need to see the server code, not the client code.

Comment: What's the ulimit on the number of open files?

Comment: @KevinLyda ulimit is 64000

Comment: @ZAky, As you mentioned, I have traced the error, the client is returning "dial tcp xyz.com : socket: too many open files"

Comment: @Adrian, It's an another project(micro service), and it's working well indepdently.